# overriding the javascript ALERT to jquery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I was trying to do the magic and turn all of my platform javascript alerts to jquery dialog, I followed the following scripts

```
<div id="overrideAlert"></div>

<script>
window.alert = function(message) {
    $('#overrideAlert').text(message).dialog({
        modal:true,
        title:'Message',
        buttons: {
            'OK':function(){
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
};
</script>
```

But no luck.

Is there a clean solution for this? Thanks,

Comment: Do you get any messaging in the console?  You have loaded jQuery and jQuery UI into the page properly, yes?

Comment: what is the problem your are facing

Comment: looks fine to me http://plnkr.co/edit/mzSKFsjvkSod1oqErdFF?p=preview

Comment: one problem could be the synchronized nature of the alert and async nature of dialog

Comment: Not sure about `dialog`, but does it auto-open or do you need to manually `.open()`?

Comment: @RickViscomi With jQuery UI Dialogs, it auto opens by default, so you have to manually tell it not to

Comment: @ArunPJohny what is this select lib you are using?

Comment: @ArunPJohny   <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.3.2/select2.js"></script>

Comment: @ComeRun that is nor required for your case, you can ignore it

Comment: @ComeRun I didn't do anything, your code was working perfectly fine

Comment: @ComeRun did you find anything wrong in your code like missing a library

Comment: @ArunPJohny yeah man some stupid mistakes like what u said ;)

Comment: @ComeRun then I'll add this as an answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would prefer a dynamic `div` instead

```
$('<div />').text(message).dialog({
    modal:true,
    title:'Message',
    buttons: {
        'OK':function(){
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    },
    close:function(){ $(this).dialog('destroy').remove(); }
});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/tBmcE/2/)

Comment: Thanks man, say I have a link and when click, an alert pops up, does this help that scenario as well?

Answer (score 3):

It just works.

Check at the ***[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uQGPB/)***.

Note: you can't call `alert('foo');` directly inside the `<head>`'s `<script>` tags, because the div element is not ready on the dom.

Comment: Thanks, does your solution cover the alerts which pop up on click? say u click a link and a confirmation pop up shows up. I want to get the jquery dialog when click on these sorts of link

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, but make sure that you add jquery and jquery-ui libraries to your page.

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mzSKFsjvkSod1oqErdFF?p=preview)

Answer (score -1):

If  we are submitting page before alert is going automatically.
some saved successfully messages there but not asking for "ok".
I have  done overriding of alert.any suggestion.
window.alert = function(message, fallback){

```
$(document.createElement('div')).attr({title: 'Alert', 'class': 'alert'}).html(message).dialog({
  buttons: {OK: function(){$(this).dialog('close'); callback()}},
  autoOpen: true,
  close:function(){$(this).remove();},
  draggable: true,
  modal: false,
  resizable: false,
  height:'auto',
  width: 'auto'
});
```